# UWP Binding not showing empty value

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I have a `ListView` containing a list of `Music` (my ViewModel), and `Music` has a `string` property `Album`.

However, when `Album` is empty, meaning that it is simply `""`, the container (a `HyperTextButton`) that holds `Album` is not showing an empty value. Instead, it shows the value of `Music.ToString()`. And although it is showing the `Music` string, the content of the `HyperTextButton` is actually empty as expected, which can be confirmed in the click event of the `HyperTextButton`.

How can I make it properly display the empty string?

This is the `ItemTemplate` of the `ListView`:

```
    <local:PlaylistControlItem DataContext="{x:Bind}" ShowAlbumText="{Binding ElementName=PlaylistController, Path=ShowAlbumText}">
        <local:PlaylistControlItem.ContextFlyout>
            <MenuFlyout Opening="OpenMusicMenuFlyout" />
        </local:PlaylistControlItem.ContextFlyout>
    </local:PlaylistControlItem>
```

And this is the `Control` that shows `Album`:

```
    <HyperlinkButton
        x:Name="AlbumTextButton"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="2"
        Margin="0,0,10,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Click="Album_Click"
        Content="{Binding Album}"
        Foreground="{Binding IsPlaying, Converter={StaticResource PlaylistRowColorConverter}, ConverterParameter=Gray, Mode=OneWay}"
        Style="{StaticResource TextButtonStyle}"
        Visibility="{x:Bind ShowAlbumText, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

The source code of `ListView` is [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/PlaylistControl.xaml).

`ItemTemplate` is [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/PlaylistControlItem.xaml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By checking your code, the main problem is in **TextButtonStyle**. In TextButtonStyle, you also use the textBlock to implement the binding. Its DataContext is Music, so it sometimes calls the Music.toString method, and in the toString method which you have rewritten returns Path, so this happens.

The quickest solution is to set the DataContext of the AlbumTextButton to Music.Album(What is changed here is just the DataContext of the AlbumTextButton , not the context of the Page.), so that the textBlock will be bound to the album. In this case, you don't need to bind the Album to the content of the Button. Or you can modify the content in the style.

TextButton.xaml:

```
<HyperlinkButton
            x:Name="AlbumTextButton"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Margin="0,0,10,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Click="Album_Click"
            DataContext="{Binding Album}"
            Foreground="{Binding IsPlaying, Converter={StaticResource PlaylistRowColorConverter}, ConverterParameter=Gray, Mode=OneWay}"
            Style="{StaticResource TextButtonStyle}"
            Visibility="{x:Bind ShowAlbumText, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

**Update:**
Method two

If you want to remove the underline, you can try to use the **TextBlockButtonStyle** which is the System provides. This usage will also not display the underline.

.xaml:

```
<HyperlinkButton
            x:Name="AlbumTextButton"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Margin="0,0,10,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Click="Album_Click"
            Content="{Binding Album}"
            Foreground="{Binding IsPlaying, Converter={StaticResource PlaylistRowColorConverter}, ConverterParameter=Gray, Mode=OneWay}"
            Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}"
            Visibility="{x:Bind ShowAlbumText, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Comment: Thank you but adding that makes the content empty.

Comment: The TextBlock in TextButtonStyle has achieved the Binding, you just need to change the DataContext.

Comment: Do you mean simply changing the `Content={Binding Album}` to `DataContext={Binding Album}` in the `HyperlinkButton`? That would make the content empty.

Comment: Yes. About this word: "That would make the content empty". Do you mean after you testing, whatever if the Album has a value, the content of the HyperlinkButton always shows empty? Or do you think that after the change will lead to empty? The HyperlinkButton uses TextButtonStyle, and the TextButtonStyle has a TextBlock can show the content.

Comment: Sorry about my phrasing. It becomes empty after I make the change, no matter what value album has (either empty or something). It shows nothing.

Comment: It's strange. When I tested it, it worked. If you remove the Style and use `Content={Binding Album}` , is the data display normal except for the underline of the HyperlinkButton?

Comment: Yes. Removing `Style` gives the expected result except for the underline. The reason why I use that `Style` is for removing the underline.

Comment: OK, If you use style just to remove the underline, you can try to use the TextBlockButtonStyle which is the System provides, like `<HyperlinkButton Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}" ......>`. This usage will also not display the underline. The TextBlock in TextButtonStyle is really the problem. If there is a problem with the solution provided before, you can try to handle it from style.

Comment: That's very helpful! Could you also update your answer?